# iOS 14 get user consent with Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, ios14

I'm not new to iOS development but this is my first time dealing with Facebook SDK. I've been following the FB guide to set up event in my app (installed SDK Swift package, added FBSDKCoreKit methods to AppDelegate), up until the very last instruction on getting user consent with iOS 14.

The Facebook guide provides this code snippet to use when getting consent with `requestTrackingAuthorization()`:

```
FBAdSettings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true)
```

Problem is the `FBAdSettings` class doesn't seem to be valid in my code (Xcode complains it cannot be found in scope), although I did `import FBSDKCoreKit` and there's no other FB modules to import.

Here is my code in full:

```
import UIKit
import AppTrackingTransparency
import FBSDKCoreKit

extension ViewController {
    func requestTrackingPermission() {
        if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { (status) in
                switch status {
                    case .authorized:
                        FBAdSettings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true)  //Cannot find 'FBAdSettings' in scope
                    ...
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You might need to import another Facebook package. Maybe [FBAudienceNetwork](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/FBAudienceNetwork/4.1.0/Classes/FBAdSettings.html)?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing, having same issue

Comment: I have the same code as you. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The documentation is at least misleading. You have to import `FBSDKCoreKit.FBSDKSettings` and the snippet is `Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true)`. As you can see, it is not `FBAdSettings` but only `Settings`.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as OP, and this doesn't seem to work for me ether. That function can't be found in the Settings module either. The closest thing I've found is `Settings.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled`

Comment: For me this solution seems to work, I will mark it as correct after some further "field" testing) I used ```import FBSDKCoreKit``` and ```FBSDKCoreKit.Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true)``` in request function.

Comment: I have no `setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled` function on `Settings`, but I can use: `Settings.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = true`

Comment: Was running an old version of Facebook SDK - updated and then could use 'setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled' too.

Comment: Note that for this to work you need `pod FBSDKCoreKit` — *not* `pod FBSDKCoreKit/Swift`! The latter would pull in the older version `6.5.2` of the SDK in which this `setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled` property does not exist.

Comment: How long does it take to reflect on Event Manager dashboard ?

Comment: Settings.shared.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = true
Settings.shared.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled = true
Settings.shared.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = true

Answer (score 5):

the right solution is to use iOS Audience Network SDK >6.0

and do:

```
 import FBAudienceNetwork
```

it will work.

Answer (score 4):

You have to import the FBAudienceNetwork library

In Objective-C

```
#include <FBAudienceNetwork/FBAdSettings.h>
```

In Swift

```
import FBAudienceNetwork
```

Answer (score 3):

I found out that you don't even need the method `Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true)` **if you just want to log events**.

So you can remove it from the authorization request, in fact the request is sufficient to activate event logging.

You can verify it by using [Facebook's Event Manager](https://www.facebook.com/micro_site/url/?click_from_context_menu=true&country=LB&destination=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fevents_manager&event_type=click&last_nav_impression_id=0krQYQTxEZRHP76A5&max_percent_page_viewed=22&max_viewport_height_px=710&max_viewport_width_px=1378&orig_http_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&orig_request_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fbusiness%2Fhelp%2F898185560232180%3Fid%3D1205376682832142&primary_cmsid=898185560232180&primary_content_locale=en_US&region=emea&scrolled=true&session_id=2ZSQP80tWQWsEdyXv&site=fb4b&extra_data%5Bview_type%5D=v3_initial_view&extra_data%5Bsite_section%5D=help&extra_data%5Bplacement%5D=%2Fbusiness%2Fhelp%2F898185560232180) to test your logged events.

Comment: I'd love to get some source as to whether this is true or not. We just want to log events so we can see the effectiveness of our Meta Campaigns so would prefer to avoid any overkill authorisation requests to users, which they would likely decline anyway. Our Meta test events works on Android, but not iOS, I am suspecting it is this advertisertracking enabled but can someone confirm whether it is required just for event logging?

Answer (score 2):

FBAdSettings is in the FBAudienceNetwork SDK, which is different from Facebook SDK. So you need to install the FBAudienceNetwork SDK(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/guides/adding-sdk/ios) and import FBAdSettings instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need the [Facebook audienceNetwork library.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/setting-up/platform-setup/ios/get-started#sdk)

Facebook has done a pretty horrible job of keeping its development docs updated.

Answer (score 1):

To manually change tracking, from version 13.0.0 and beyond, you need to use `Settings.shared` in places where `Settings` was used before.

[Changelog](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#settings-deprecations):

> Removed deprecated Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(_:) (use the
> Settings.shared.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled property to set a value
> instead")

If you are using version 13.0.0 and beyond, use

```
 Settings.shared.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled = true
```

instead of

```
 Settings.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled = true
```

Be advised that beyond iOS 14.5 you need to ask the user for permissions first, example usaged below:

```swift
   func requestTracking(){
                     if #available(iOS 14, *) {
                         ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { (status) in
                             switch status {
                             case .authorized:
                                 Settings.shared.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = true
                                 Settings.shared.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled = true
                                 Settings.shared.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = true
                                 break
                             case .denied:
                                 Settings.shared.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = false
                                 Settings.shared.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled = false
                                 Settings.shared.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = false
                                 break
                             default:
                                 break
                             }
                         })
                     } else {
                         Settings.shared.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = true
                         Settings.shared.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled = true
                         Settings.shared.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = true
                     }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution using Objective C:

in Podfile (located under ios/)

```
target 'my_app' do:
     pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'
     pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
   ... other code ...
```

in AppDelegate.m:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#include <FBAudienceNetwork/FBAdSettings.h>


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
       [FBAdSettings setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled:YES];
... other code ...
}
```

Run `rm -rf Pods` where your pods directory is.
Run `pod install`

Ended up installing these versions in case it matters:

- FBSDKCoreKit (12.2.1)
- FBAudienceNetwork (6.9.0)

Answer (score 0):

**A Little Tip**

If you have a function named **"Settings"**, it calls "setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled" in the methods inside the **"Settings"** function that you wrote for another job and gives an error.

You can **change your "Settings" function name** or use **"FBSDKCoreKit.Settings"**. This way you can call "setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled".