# Facebook SDK set advertiser tracking enabled is not exist iOS14

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, ios14

I use facebook ads in my app and I'm trying to implement the requestTrackingAuthorization,
I'm using the latest FB SDK "swift version" and I can not find the code snippet provided by [FB guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/guides/advertising-tracking-enabled/)

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBAudienceNetwork

// Set the flag as true
FBAdSettings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true)
// Set the flag as false
FBAdSettings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(false)
```

what I found instead is:

```
Settings.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = Bool
```

and I'm not sure if it the same or not, I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64791812/ios-14-get-user-consent-with-facebook-sdk) and none of the solutions worked, my code ended up like this:

```
import FBAudienceNetwork
import FBSDKCoreKit

ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { status in
        switch status {
        case .notDetermined:
            break
        case .restricted:
            Settings.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = false
            Settings.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = false
            
        case .denied:
            Settings.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = false
            Settings.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = false
            
        case .authorized:
            Settings.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = true
            Settings.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = true
            
        @unknown default:
            Settings.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = false
            Settings.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = false
        }
    }
```

so:

1- why I can not find setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled in FBAdSettings neither Settings

2- is isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled same as setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled ?

Comment: I got from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64791812/ios-14-get-user-consent-with-facebook-sdk) correct answer that the import was the problem for me.
You need to import `import FBSDKCoreKit.FBSDKSettings` (and have at least version 8.0.0 I think).

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to import the FBAudienceNetwork library

In Objective-C

```
#include <FBAudienceNetwork/FBAdSettings.h>
```

In Swift

```
import FBAudienceNetwork
```

2. They are not the same, according to the FB Documentation

> [isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/current/FBSDKCoreKit/classes/fbsdksettings.html/) : Controls the access to IDFA If not
> explicitly set, the default is true
>
> [setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/guides/advertising-tracking-enabled/) : This allows you to inform Audience
> Network whether to use the data to deliver personalized ads

Answer (score 0):

For anybody trying to implement this without the need of FBAudienceNetwork `isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled` is now inside `shared` (swift) or `sharedSettings` (objective c) of `FBSDKSettings`.
In my case, in order to implement it on a react native app, I needed:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKSettings.h>
...

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [FBSDKSettings.sharedSettings setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled:YES];
}
```

For swift it would be:

```
Settings.shared.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled = true
```