# Cannot find "FBAdSettings.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true)"

Tags: facebook, ios14

Currently I am integrating Facebook SDK but SDK cannot find

"FBAdSettings.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true)"

I've done everything facebook guide said but this error still comes out.
What am I missing?

Facebook Guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/setting-up/platform-setup/ios/advertising-tracking-enabled/

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    // Create AdBrixRM Instance
    let adBrix = AdBrixRM.getInstance
    
    FBAudienceNetworkAds.initialize(with: nil, completionHandler: nil)

    FBAdSettings.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true)
    
    
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization {(status) in
            switch status{
            case.authorized:
                adBrix.startGettingIDFA()
                Settings.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = true
                

                
            case.denied:
                adBrix.stopGettingIDFA()
                Settings.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = false

                
            case.notDetermined :
                adBrix.stopGettingIDFA()
                Settings.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = false

                

            case.restricted:
                adBrix.stopGettingIDFA()
                Settings.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = false


            default:
                adBrix.stopGettingIDFA()
                Settings.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = false


            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Do not post codes as screenshots. please paste your code and format it well in your question.

Comment: @Raptor Sorry for the inconvenience. I just add my code.

Comment: I bet you will find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66842893/188331

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to import the FBAudienceNetwork library:

In Objective-C

> #include <FBAudienceNetwork/FBAdSettings.h>

In Swift

> import FBAudienceNetwork

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate settings:

1. `Settings.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = true` which I think notifies FB SDK that you want it to track IDFA
   (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/current/FBSDKCoreKit/classes/fbsdksettings.html/)
2. `Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true)` which notifies FB SDK that user approved the new iOS 14.5 privacy tracking permission
   (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/guides/advertising-tracking-enabled)

It seems you somehow combined those two into one :) So just pick the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another way: `Settings.shared.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled = true` And add Framework included:

1. FBAEMKit
2. FBSDKCoreKit_Basics
3. FBSDKCoreKit