# Where is the FBAdSettings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true) method?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-sdk-4.x

I try to set follow in this document but I not found this method?

link to set https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/guides/advertising-tracking-enabled[enter link description here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/guides/advertising-tracking-enabled)

link to pod SDK https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/guides/adding-sdk/ios

and link solution integrate https://www.facebook.com/fbgaminghome/blog/preparing-our-partners-for-ios14-latest-guidance-skadnetwork

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64791812/ios-14-get-user-consent-with-facebook-sdk