# How to enable or disable the iOSAdvertiserTrackingEnabled tag with respect to the user consent in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, ios-permissions, facebook-ads

I wants to implement the Meta rewarded Ads in flutter for both android and IOS. For that, the tag iOSAdvertiserTrackingEnabled is necessary for the IOS 14 & +. Any body have an idea to get the user consent for the flutter - IOS app.

I just referred the link of documentation of meta below,
[documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/setting-up/platform-setup/ios/advertising-tracking-enabled)

Now I need a method or way to implement the consent getting section in flutter , Documentation specify only the use in IOS.

Any idea should be appreciated.

#Tried below
I researched everywhere but getting only the implementation in IOS only, Not in flutter.

#Some details got from the documentation regarding the flag, mentioned below,

#How to Use the Flag

1.AdvertiserTrackingEnabled is only available for iOS 14 or later users. If you are running iOS 13 or earlier, Limit Ad Tracking is used.
2.Set the AdvertiserTrackingEnabled flag to either true or false. In iOS versions where Apple enforces the prompt, if you do not set the ATE flag it defaults to false.
3.The flag is incorporated into each ad request or bidder token automatically. You do not need to call the initilize() method additionally.
4.The true or false setting will remain at your chosen value until you manually change it. However, if the user uninstalls and reinstalls your app, you must set the flag again.

Got an IOS snippet for IOS , given reference below,

[stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64791812/ios-14-get-user-consent-with-facebook-sdk)

#Needs

To implement the consent in flutter app, Implementation